# C# Прозрачное окно не пропускает клики мышки | Виджет

Tags: c#, winforms

C# Winforms, создал окно, которое по кнопке делается прозрачным и наоборот, но в области размера окна при прозрачном режиме не кликабельно всё что под ним. Есть ли возможность это решить? Хочу написать что-то типа виджета.
Для прозрачности использовал это:

```
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
this.AllowTransparency = true;
this.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
this.TransparencyKey = this.BackColor;
```

Comment: Есть возможность. Например писать на WPF который это позволяет, а не пытаться выдавить из winforms то, для чего он не предназначен)

Comment: Понял, можно тогда подсказку как на WPF реализовать?)

Comment: google -> "Transparent click through wpf control"

Comment: В WPF искать и пробовать [`IsHitTestVisible`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible?view=netframework-4.8), либо фон окна должен быть `Background="{x:Null}"`.

Comment: Можно использовать функции WinAPI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2798294/5045688